# detect the service's project package name at runtime

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have built two [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) projects written in TypeScript. Each project is a microservice.

I have also developed a shared library project in typescript.  The two microservices projects mentioned above are using this library.

Now, in library project function, I need to detect which microservice is calling the function at runtime:

```
// this is the shared library project
const foo = () => {
   // I need to know the name of the micro-service that is defined in its package.json 
   // to identify who is now calling this function
}
```

I might be wrong but I feel the ideal way would be to get the `name` of the service project declared in its `package.json`. For example, I'd like to detect this is `my-service-one` if this service's project `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "my-service-one",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  ...
  ...
}
```

I tried to sniff from `process` object, but no such information at runtime.  Inside the library project code, how to detect which service is calling the library function then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import the `package.json` directly, though be warned that can mess with the `dist` output due to how Typescript works (instead of `dist/main` you get `dist/src/main`). The other option would be to use `JSON.parse()` and `readFile` from the `fs` package. Something like

```js
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import * as path from 'path';

const packageJson = JSON.parse(
  await readFile(
    path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      'package.json',
    )
  )
);
const { name, version } = packageJson;
```